# Use String value instead of Constant String in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the function I want to run on button press, it requires `const` String value in `data` field.

When I use `packageNameImported` instead of `packageName` it gives an error that String has to be constant. 

Is there any way i can pass value from button to this function on press?

```
  deleteApp(String packageNameImported) {
    const packageName = 'package.name.app';
    final AndroidIntent intent = const AndroidIntent(
      action: 'action_delete',
      data: 'package:' + packageName,
    );
    intent.launch();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constant functions require constant values

Change

```
final AndroidIntent intent = const AndroidIntent(
```

to

```
final AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
```